# Problems by getting selected text from other programs

Tags: c#, windows, clipboard

I am writing a program to replace some strings in a text (from another window) with others. For example, if the text is originally "Char: &auml;", it should be replaced by "Char: ä". The problem is to get and set the text in the host window. If I try the same code several times, sometimes it works, but most of the time nothing happens or the clipboard gets cleared. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();  // Save current clipboard content

    Thread.Sleep(100);
    SendKeys.Send("^(c)");  // Copy selected text from different program to clipboard
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    if (!Clipboard.ContainsText())  // Check for invaild data
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred!");
        return;
    }

    string text = Clipboard.GetText();  // Get text from clipboard

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> shortcut in shortcuts)  // Enumerate dictionary to modify the text
    {
        text = text.Replace(shortcut.Key, shortcut.Value);  // Modify text
    }
    
    Clipboard.SetText(text);  // Load modified text to clipboard

    Thread.Sleep(100);
    SendKeys.Send("^(v)");  // Paste modified text
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);  // Restore old clipboard content
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred!");
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the key should be enclosed in parentheses? `^v` instead of `^(v)`

Comment: @hijinxbassist I have read on some websites that you should use `^(v)`. It works sometimes, the question is why not every time. But I tested it without brackets, and it didn't get any better.

Comment: Maybe the application you are capturing from is not the active application?  Docs: "Use SendKeys to send keystrokes and keystroke combinations to the **active application**."

Comment: It is the active application, I have also tested it with different ones.